# How can i find the cell with text="123" in the spreadsheet from Google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you help me with my issue please?
        I need to: 
        find all "var text = data.message.text;" in the spreadsheet 
        and send text in the same row but next colomn to the telegram
        for example:
        spreadsheet:
        111       7       sdf       sdfsd
        222       4       sdv      asdfasdf
        333      11     sdfs     sdfsdfsdf
        222      15     sdf       sdfsdfsdf
        555      3       asdf     asdfasdfas

```
    if the user in telegram enters 222
    bot has to send him:
    4
    15

    I will be very grateful to you!!!

    spreadsheet can be like this:
    Genri    111       7       sdf       sdfsd
    Ford     222       4       sdv      asdfasdf
    Suzi     333      11     sdfs     sdfsdfsdf

    in Delphi it seems like this
    for example spreadsheet placed in array a

    For i:=1 to maxColomns do
     For j:=1 to maxRaws do
         if a[i,j]=text then sendText(id,a[i,j+1]);

    but i don't know the functions in gs(((


    Telegram script bot

    youtube.com - Telegram Bot Tutorial: How to connect your Telegram Bot to a Google Spreadsheet (Apps Script)

    // FULL SCRIPT BELOW:
    // How to connect your Telegram Bot to a Google Spreadsheet (Google Apps Script)
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSXd...
    // 
    // FILL IN THE GLOBAL VARIABLES token, webAppUrl and ssId
    //

    var token = ""; // FILL IN YOUR OWN TOKEN
    var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
    var webAppUrl = ""; // FILL IN YOUR GOOGLE WEB APP ADDRESS
    var ssId = ""; // FILL IN THE ID OF YOUR SPREADSHEET

    function getMe() {
      var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }

    function setWebhook() {
      var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }

    function sendText(id,text) {
      var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }

    function doGet(e) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");
    }

    function doPost(e) {
      // this is where telegram works
      var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
      var text = data.message.text;
      var id = data.message.chat.id;
      var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
      var answer = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment " + text;
      sendText(id,answer);
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);

      if(/^@/.test(text)) {
        var sheetName = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
        var comment = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name,comment,answer]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried while working on this problem?

Comment: i did this:

  var maxColomns = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].getLastColumn();
  var maxRaws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].getLastRow();
  
  var i = 0;
  while (i < maxColomns+1) {
    var j = 0;
    while (i < maxRaws+1) {
      if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange()[i][j].getValue() = text){
        
      }
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }

but i think 
if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange()[i][j].getValue() = text)

isn't correct

Comment: i did this:
        var maxColomns = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].getLastColumn();
        var maxRaws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].getLastRow();
        
        var i = 0;
        while (i < maxColomns+1) {
          var j = 0;
          while (i < maxRaws+1) {
            if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange()[i][j].getValue() = text){
              
            }
            j++;
          }
          i++;
        }

Comment: @FRowe
      but i think 
      if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange‌​()[i][j].getValue() = text)
      isn't correct

Comment: Add your code snippets to the question so you can properly format for readability.

Comment: but i think ""if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].setActiveRange‌​‌​()[i][j].getValue(‌​) == text)"" isn't correct

Comment: how can i get the value of the cell[i][j] , to compare with the text?

Comment: Thanks to all, i've done it.